# fade-in/fade-out gallery of images in css at particular position

Tags: html, css, css-animations, fadein, fadeout

I have a fiddle as shown below in which at the **position 4(marked by yellow circle)** from the left where **picture 6** is showing, I want **cross-fade(fade-in/fade-out)** gallery of images to happen.

At position 4, I want **cross-fade (fade-in/fade-out)** of **3 images(Picture 4, Picture 5, Picture 6)** to happen.

[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/k0vzthne/embedded/result

This is the CSS codes which I have used. At this moment, I don't see any cross-fade (fade-in/fade-out) gallery of images going on at position 4.

```
.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(5), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 568px;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}


.featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 8s;
}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;z-index: 999;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;z-index: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the fiddle so that at position 4, fade-in/fade-out of 3 images happen.

Comment: Since you're using Flexbox, you can change the order of your tiles using the [`order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property.

Comment: Why don't you just copy the code from the similar example and replace the images? The trick is absolute positioning and animation-delay for the nth-of-type items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with display: flex to a container and absolute position for child on it, as described [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items).

With that on mind, this is my answer:

```css
.featured-block {width: 1000px;}
.featured-block a { display: inline-block; opacity: 1;}

a:nth-of-type(4), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(5), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) { 
  position: absolute; 
  animation: 12s infinite ease-in-out cf4FadeInOut;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index:1;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4) { animation-delay: 0s; }
.featured-block a:nth-of-type(5) { animation-delay: 4s; }
.featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) { animation-delay: 8s; }

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

```html
<div class="featured-block">
  
  <a href="https://www.google.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%201" data-fallback-img="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%201" alt="Outburst">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%202" data-fallback-img="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%202" 
  alt="L'Essentiel with Esther Bégin">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%203" data-fallback-img="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%203" alt="Outburst">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://www.twiiter.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%204" data-fallback-img="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%204" alt="L'Essentiel with Esther Bégin">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  
   <a href="https://www.amazon.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%205" data-fallback-img="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%205" alt="Outburst">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>
  
  <a href="https://www.expedia.com/" class="featured-block__item cf">
    <div class="featured-block__item-inner">
      <figure class="featured-block__image img-fit" itemprop="image" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageObject">
        <img class="default-opacity" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%206" data-fallback-img="https://via.placeholder.com/200x100?text=picture%206" alt="L'Essentiel with Esther Bégin">
      </figure>
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. On clicking an image, its not pointing to any link. In short, on clicking Picture 4 it should point to twitter.com, Picture 5 amazon.com, Picture 6 expedia.com.

Comment: @john on fiddle it's not pointing to any link due restrictions, but if you test it local / on your server it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the animation name:

```
.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(5), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 568px;
  animation: 12s infinite ease-in-out cf4FadeInOut;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

take a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/j4oxmcsL/embedded/result)

**Edit:**

The key to display order issue is to use negative animation delay:

```
.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(5), .featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) {
  position: absolute;
  right: 568px;
  animation: 12s infinite ease-in-out cf4FadeInOut;
  opacity:0;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(4) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(5) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.featured-block a:nth-of-type(6) {
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes cf4FadeInOut {
    0% {opacity: 0;}
    20% {opacity: 1;}
    33% {opacity: 1;}
    53% {opacity: 0;}
    100% {opacity: 0;}
}
```

take a [look](https://jsfiddle.net/74trsuqk/9/embedded/result)

Comment: On page load, it starts from `Picture 6` and then `Picture 4`, `Picture 5` and `Picture 6`. I am wondering what changes I need to make so that on page load it starts from Picture 4 => Picture 5 => Picture 6

Comment: Solved the display order issue, please see the updated answer.